# Convert Enum to string inside TextBlock text

Tags: wpf, xaml, enums

I have simple `Enum`:

```
public enum StatusMessage
{
    Cancel,
    Done,
    [Description("In process...")]
    InProcess,
    [Description("We have delay...")]
    Delay,
    Waiting
}
```

And `GridViewColumn`:

My property:

```
StatusMessage StatusMsg;
```

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="180" Header="Status" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMsg}" Foreground="{Binding StatusMsg,Converter={my:StatusMessageToColorConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

And i have this `EnumToStringConverter`:

```
public class EnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string EnumString;
        try
        {
            EnumString = Enum.GetName((value.GetType()), value);
            return EnumString;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now i want to use this `Convertor` inside my `TextBlock` :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusMsg, Converter={my:EnumToStringConverter}}" Foreground="{Binding StatusMsg,Converter={my:StatusMessageToColorConverter}}" />
```

So the problem is that i have this error:

> 'my:EnumToStringConverter' is used like a markup extension but does
>   not derive from MarkupExtension.

What is this `MarkupExtension` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare an instance of the EnumToStringConverter in XAML.  It can be a local resource or declared in app.xaml to make it accessible everywhere.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:EnumToStringConverter x:Key="DefaultEnumToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use it like this:

```
Text="{Binding StatusMsg, Converter={StaticResource DefaultEnumToStringConverter}}"
```

Note the word "StaticResource" in the converter.  That is the markup extension. This one tells WPF to go find the static resource with the key "DefaultEnumToStringConverter".  WPF will search up the visual tree of the element looking for a resource with that key.  If one isn't found it will check at the application level in `app.xaml`.

MarkupExtensions are the things at the beginning of an attribute enclosed in the {}, "x", "binding", "static", etc.  They are what give WPF the ability to resolve the text attribute in to a useful object instance.  You can create your own MarkupExtensions to do some pretty cool things.

In your particular example it is complaining because it is looking for a markup extension named "my", from the inner `Converter={my:EnumToStringConverter}`.

Comment: I have this one: xmlns:my="clr-namespace:myApplication.classes" inside my project (MyApplication) i have the folder classes and inside i have this EnumToStringConverter class

Comment: That is an `xml namespace`, not a `MarkupExtension`.  You will still need that `xmlns` in whatever XAML file you choose to declare the Converter instance in though, so don't get rid of it.

Comment: I put it inside windows resources and i have this error: Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

Comment: ahh, sorry, that was my mistake. "x:Name" should be "x:Key".  I fixed my example.

Comment: There is no static inside Converter, Error 54 The type 'static:DefaultEnumToStringConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: hah, sorry, it's been a long night and I don't have Visual Studio open right now, I'm working from memory, try "StaticResource" instead of "Static"

Comment: This should be StaticResource DefaultEnumToStringConverter